# understanding constructors in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a Scala class definition as follows:

```
case class Node(factor: Factor, gate: Gate) extends GenericNode(factor)
```

Now, there is never any line in the class that stores this passed Gate variable in the class but the methods use it. So one can have a method like:

```
def compute(): factor
    val p = gate.getParam()
```

I am from a C++ background, so this is new for me. So, all the variables passed in the class definition have the scope during the lifetime of the object instance or does it automatically get copied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That part of your code:

```
class Node(factor: Factor, gate: Gate)
```

declares a class `Node` with 2 class parameters. This means you automatically get a constructor (called the primary constructor) that accepts 2 variables as input that automatically copies them as private class members. You can access those later from within the class through `this.factor` and `this.gate`. If you had declared them as `val`, they would also automatically have been accessible from outside the class.

This part of your code:

```
extends GenericNode(factor)
```

says that `Node`inherits from `GenericNode` and that the constructor of `GenericNode` (superclass) will be called with the value received as `factor`in the primary constructor of Node

Comment: Primary constructor parameters to non-`case` classes that do not bear the `val` keyword are only copied to private fields if they're referenced outside of the constructor code (i.e., if they're referenced from in method bodies or in `lazy val` initialization expressions).

Comment: `case class` constructor parameters are by default public, so there's no need to prepend them with `val`s.

Answer (score 2):

A `case class` is a special type of class in scala, providing some convenience features over standard classes. One of these features is making all constructor parameters publicly visible on the instances of the class. For normal, "non-case" classes this works differently, the constructor parameters there are only accessible inside the class (working like read-only private fields) unless they are prefixed with one of the the `val` or `var` keywords.

For case classes the compiler also generates a companion object (an object having the same name as the class), with an apply and an unapply method, where the first can be used to construct new instances of the class, while the second is used to perform pattern matching on instances of the class. You should also check out this [blog post](http://bplawler.tumblr.com/post/7493366722/scala-programming-unapply-and-case-classes) for a good description of case classes.

Comment: "the constructor parameters there are only accessible in the default constructor (the body of the class)" No, they are also accessible in any member of the class.